# Android-Change Edittext after each change

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

how can i add Char such as this dash '-' after each change in edtitext for example if the user enter A then the text in edittext will be A- then the user will complete and enter Char B then the edittext will be A-B 
How to implement this ? thanks

```
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                 name.setText("-");
                }
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){


               }
```

Comment: Like PH7 said in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459966/android-change-edittext-after-each-change/7460503#7460503) bellow, you are into an infinite loop, and just as a reminder, don't forget that when you make a call to EditText.setText() you are wiping all the content that was previously in the edittext box and replacing it, not just appending.

Comment: @Dev you got solution of your question

Answer (score 4):

You are having infinite loop as described in Android Doc

> but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.

So all you have to do is just imposing a condition to avoid infinite loop. For example,

```
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.charAt(s.length()-1)!='-'){
                s.append("-");
            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

    });
```

Comment: When I add s.append("-"), then my editText show me:  whatever-  , but the cursor appears one character behind '-' , when I put the editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()) , Still the cursor appears in the same position. Can you help me a little?

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), using [`addTextChangedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).

Comment: I already use the Textwatcher but when i call setText show an exception

Answer (score 1):

Append the `-` char in `beforeTextChagned`

```
  name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
             name.setText(s+"-");
         }
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
  }
```

Comment: still force close , I don't know why . if I remove setText() there is no force close

Comment: where can i find the exception , I'm beginner in android

Answer (score 0):

```
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               try{    
                     name.setText(s.toString()+"-");
               }catch(exception e)
              {
               e.printStackTrace();
              } 
                    }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

               }
```

Comment: thanks but  when i start to write A the app will force stop :(

Comment: please help , I don't know why force stop

Comment: then try catch what exception its throwing see my edited code

Comment: how can I see the exception ?