# Force close when add setText()

Tags: android, listener, settext

the following is my code :

```
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


             name.setText(s.toString()+"-");
                }
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ }
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){ }
            });
```

But I get the app to force close , when remove setText() the app works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459966/android-change-edittext-after-each-change

Refer to your previous question.

Comment: When app is force closed there is usually exact reason in logcat. Please post your logcat.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting stuck in your `afterTextChanged` method, because right after you `setText`, it is called again, and again, and again... You have to find another way, how/when to append the "-" character.

Comment: Try to think, when do you need the "-" there. Is it right after you write something? Or is it enough later, when you press some button or so.

Comment: Maybe you should try after focus lost. See setOnFocusChangeListener, maybe it should work.

Comment: so Michell Bak's post will fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this question I asked some time ago. It's a lot like your question:

[Changing text in Android on text change causes overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222944/changing-text-in-android-on-text-change-causes-overflow-error)